# How to install a specific version of Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I have an existing project and I want to install the angular material in same project.
The problem is that the project is in Angular (6.1.5) and the global version of my cli is (8.1.0).
Although I tried but its no more working. Please help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can install a specific version of Angular Material (version 6+) by doing this.

```
npm install @angular/material@6.4.7
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have to install an older version of a package, just specify it

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Angular's schematic add cli command

```bash
ng add @angular/material@version

# example
ng add @angular/material@14.2.7
```

ref: https://v15.material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

---

### Why this method?

Prompts you to install additional components based on the experience you want.

Based on the prompts you chose, will automatically update the following files for you:

- angular.json
- your global defined stylesheet
- src/index.html
- package.json
- package-lock.json